# Every abelian normal subgroup of a connected and compact Lie group lies in the center

Tags: lie-groups, compact-manifolds

### Show that every abelian normal subgroup $H$ of a connected and compact Lie group $G$ lies in the center of $G$.

It may be helpfull that if $f:G\to H$ is a surjective lie group homomorphism with $H$ a abelian group, then the restriction $f|_T$ of $f$ to any maximal torus $T$ is also surjective.

But here is what I am trying: take $h\in H$ and $g\in G$. As $H$ is normal, one has that there is a $h'\in H$ s.t.
$$gh=h'g$$
My attempt is to show that $h'=h$.

Let $T$ be a maximal torus in $G$. One has that there is $r\in G\setminus T$ and $t\in T$ s.t.
$$rtr^{-1}=h.$$
As $H$ is normal, $t\in H\cap T$.

Thus,
$$(gr)t(gr)^{-1}=h'.$$

But I'm stuck here. Also I'm not using that $H$ is abelian.

Comment: Something must be missing. $A_3$ is an abelian normal subgroup of $S_3$, but not central. If you want to exclude $0$-dimensional Lie groups, take $A_3 \times S^1$ as a normal abelian subgroup of $S_3 \times S^1$. Or $SO(2) \subset O(2)$.

Comment: Weird. It is the exercise 6 in chapter IV section 1 in the Theodor Bröcker's book "Representations of Compact Lie Groups".

Comment: Perhaps connected ?

Comment: Maybe he only considers connected Lie groups. I don't know whether that would make it correct, but it's the only idea that comes to mind.

Comment: It is connected. I have just seen it.

Answer (score 2):

To give a more elementary solution: Let $H^0$ be the identity component of $H$.
$H^0$ is compact, connected and abelian, hence it is a torus and is contained in a maximal torus $T$. Thus,
$$H^0 = g H^0 g^{-1} \subset gTg^{-1}$$
Since all maximal tori are conjugates of each other, $H^0$ is contained in all of them and hence in the center of $G$ (This is Theorem 2.3 part (iii) pg. 165 in Theodor Brocker's Representation of Compact Lie Groups)

In the case that $H$ is disconnected, let $h\in H\backslash H^0$ and let $T_h$ be a maximal torus that contains $h$. Observe that $H/H^0$ is a discrete normal subgroup of $G/H^0$ and hence it is abelian. From this we get that for all $g\in G$ there exists an $h_0 \in H^0$ such that:
$$g h g^{-1} = h\, h_0$$
Finally, this means that the set $c_G(h) = \{ g h g^{-1}: \ \forall g\in G\}$ is contained in $T_h$ because both $h$ and $h_0$ are contained in $T_h$. With the same argument as before,
$$c_G(h) = g\, c_G(h) \, g^{-1} \subset gT_h g^{-1}$$
and this means that $c_G(h)$ is contained in all maximal tori of $G$.

Answer (score 0):

It results from the structure of connected compact Lie group, since $G$ is the quotient $S\times T$ of a semi simple group $S$ and a torus $H$ by a central subgroup. If $p$ is the quotient  map, $p^{-1}(H)$ is normal and abelian so contained in $e\times T$.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_group

Comment: And why does that mean that $H$ is central?

Comment: Also, why is $p^{-1}(H)$ abelian?